# sed command to replace last occurrence of a word in a file with the content of another file

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing, sed, macos

1. macOS `sed` command to replace last occurrence of a word in a file
2. Replace with the content from another file
3. Replace only the last occurrence, means only once.
4. The word can be a substring `abchello` or `helloabc`
5. There can be trailing whitespace or newline after the word

sample_file_path = "/Users/saurav/sample.text"
sample_file_path_1 = "/Users/saurav/sample1.text"

`sample.txt`:

```
hello
hi
hello
ok
```

`sample1.txt`:

```
I
am 
doing
great
```

Expected output (`sample.txt`):

```
hello
hi
I
am 
doing
great
ok
```

Need to use file path variable

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details. Should this be done for _all_ words that occur more than once? What if a word occurs more than twice, should we only change the last instance? Can multiple words occur more than once? Can a word be a substring? Can you have `othello` for example and should that count as a match of `hello`? Does it absolutely need to be `sed` or are you open to tools like `awk` or `perl`?

Comment: @terdon Updated the question, with all your queries

Comment: I don't think this is even possible in sed. Or, if it is, would probably require a very, very convoluted script. You would need to read the file twice (once to get the words and another to get the last occurrence) and then replace it and repeat for every repeated word. Sed just isn't the right tool here. Both awk and perl are installed by default on macOS, are you sure you don't want to use something more suited to the task? Also, you haven't clarified if "last" always means "second" or if it can be Nth, nor if you can have multiple duplicated words.

Comment: Understood, I am new to shell scripting. I tried with awk and perl which works fine on osx. @terdon please suggest a command based on awk or perl to achieve that

Comment: OK, but you still haven't told us what words to replace. Is it any word that occurs more than once in the file? Only some words that occur more than once? Is the last time always the second time or can there be more?

Comment: You ha have shown Hello on a line by itself. what if hello has other stuff on the same line then how should the replacement happen?

Comment: Wait, do you only want to replace the specific word `hello`? I thought you want to do this for any word that occurs more than once. Are you saying that you will know the target word in advance?

Comment: Yes, @terdon I know the target word in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In three steps, using `sed` syntax compatible with `/usr/bin/sed` on macOS, and either `bash` or `zsh` (the two main shells on current macOS systems):

```bsh
sed -n '/hello/=' sample.txt |
sed -e '$!d' -e $'s/.*/&r sample1.txt\\\n&d/' |
sed -f /dev/stdin sample.txt
```

This uses `sed` in three steps:

1. Finds all lines in `sample.txt` that matches `hello` and output the line numbers corresponding to those lines.
2. Deletes all but the last line number outputted by the first step (using `$!d`, "if this is not the last line, delete it"), and creates a two-line `sed` script that would modify the last matching line by first reading `sample1.txt` and then deleting the original line.  Given that the last match of `hello` is on line 3 in the original file, this script would look like

   ```
   3r sample1.txt
   3d
   ```
3. Applies the constructed `sed` script on the file `sample.txt`.

Would you want to make the edit "in-place", so that the original `sample.txt` is modified, then use

```bsh
sed -n '/hello/=' sample.txt |
sed -e '$!d' -e $'s/.*/&r sample1.txt\\\n&d/' |
sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin sample.txt
```

---

The same set of commands, but using your variables `$sample_file_path` and `$sample_file_path_1` for the two file paths:

```bsh
sed -n '/hello/=' "$sample_file_path" |
sed -e '$!d' -e 's,.*,&r '"$sample_file_path_1"$'\\\n&d,' |
sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin "$sample_file_path"
```

Note that I have changed the delimiters in the second command from `/` to `,` as the file path contains slashes.  You may use any character as a delimiter in the `s///` command that is not otherwise part of the regular expression or replacement text.

Comment: @Kushalananda Thanks a lot!!! It works as expected

Comment: @Kushalananda If it's an empty file and there is no match, is there a way we still insert the text?

Comment: @Saurav `[ ! -s sample.txt ] && cp sample1.txt sample.txt`

Comment: and please suggest a tutorial where I can learn all these, and not bother you guys in future :D

Comment: @Saurav I can recommend trying to solve issues on this site, or read and test other people's answers. I don't know any other on-line tutorials. I've learnt by solving real problems, and this site is full of these.

Comment: Is there a way to use the path, like /Users/saurav/Fastfile as a variable $fatstfile_path within sed command? Right now I'm getting error `bad flag in substitute command: 'U'`

Comment: @Saurav Sure. It will look a bit wonky but it will work:  `sed -e '$!d' -e 's/.*/&r '"$fatstfile_path"$'\\\n&d/'`

Comment: `sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin $fastfile_path`    or  `sed -i '' -f /dev/stdin '"$fatstfile_path"$'` doesn't work, error filename expected

Comment: Can you please help in using file path all three command, instead of directly using the file. I did try to find but couldn't so far

Comment: @Saurav Use `"$fatstfile_path"` instead of `sample.txt`.  It would have been easier if you had mentioned these things in your question. Note that the command I mentioned in my last comment was for the middle of the three command, where you originally had `sample1.txt`, i.e. the filename of the file with the contents that should be inserted, not `sample.txt`.

Comment: sed -e '$!d' -e 's/.*/&r '"$fasttfile_path"$'\\\n&d/' Also doesn't work. Getting bad flag in substitute command: 'U'. Now updated the question as well with the need using file path

Comment: @Saurav See added bit at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try `tac` and  `awk` combination:

```
tac sample.txt \
| awk -v replacement="$(tac sample1.txt)" '/hello/ && !n++ {gsub(/hello/,replacement,$0)}1' \
| tac
```

Note, this will also replace the `hello` part from `nothello`. If you want to replace only independent `hello`, you need to add word boundaries to the pattern: `/\<hello\>/` instead of `/hello/`

Answer (score 2):

With a single invocation + using the `Posix`-ly constructs of `sed` we can do as shown. The USP of this approach is that the sed code itself generates the file which it shall read later into the printing stream.

```
sed -n '
  /\n/{
    s/.$//w file.tmp
    b a
  }
  /hello/!{
    H;1h;$!d
    s/.*//;x
    //!{p;q;}
    G;D
  }
  x;1!p;$!d;:a
  r file2
  r file.tmp
' file1
```

Brief explanation of how it works:

- Accumulate hello line and the subsequent non hello lines in hold space.
- Now when we read the next line and it happens to be hello, then we know that the hello line in space cannot be the last, so we flush out the hold area.
- This is the next cycle of events wherein we store the hello line at the top and subsequent non hellos underneath it.
- The cycle (flush hold;store /hello/+!/hello/+!/hello/...) keeps going on until we hit the EOF.
- Now at eof, one of the 3 possible scenarios can arise:

  - There never was a /hello/ line in the whole file, so the hold ballooned to contain the total lines and we flush it via the `//!{p;q;}` construct. At this stage, we already are at eof and we tested for the regex /hello/ , so we can reuse it as `//`.
  - Second scenario is hold had /hello/+atleast one non hello. What we need to do here is clip the top of the hold , the /hello/ line, and replace it with the contents of `file2` since this is the LAST /hello/ line. But the fly in the ointment is we want the other portion (the non hello lines). If we just did `r file2` this would place the contents at the end. So we have to come up with something to overcome it. What we do is , store these non hello lines in a file and then do a `r tmpfile` . Pbm solved.
  - Third possibility is the last line was a hello line. Here the tmpfile would not exist and we exploit the property of read command to not complain about non existent files.

Comment: That really could do with some explanation. It looks like random noise! :)

Comment: Added a brief explanation of the working.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `sed` stream editor utility to get the desired output.

```
sed -n '
  /hello/!{
    H;1h;$!d;g
    s///w file.tmp
    t a
    p;q
  }
  x;1!p;$!d
  :a
  r file2
' file1
sed -e '1d' file.tmp
```

- accumulates the lines in hold until it sees the `hello` line
- on a `hello` line, it prints what was saved in hold and starts the cycle again.
- only at `EOF` or the last line we print the hold and pattern spaces.

---

Or, another way is the `tac`-`perl`-`tac` pipeline:

```
tac file1 |
perl -0777 -pe 's?hello\n?qx/tac file2/?e' - | 
tac
```